# Passing XPath as param to XSLT by C#,

Tags: c#, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Not really sure about the significance of this method but just I feel like trying it. Instead of using XML DOM and reading Value by using XPath directly in C#, Is it possible to pass string as a param to XSLT and in XSLT use it as XPath?

C#:

```
.........
......

XsltArgumentList xslArg = new XsltArgumentList();
xslArg.AddParam("XPathTest", "", SomedynamicString);
XsltSettings xslsettings = new XsltSettings(false, true);
xslTransform.Load(string_xslInput, xslsettings, new XmlUrlResolver());
xslTransform.Transform(xpathXmlOrig, xslArg, objMemoryStream);
.........
......
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:crnObj="urn:UTCCalc">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:param name="XPathTest"/>
.........
.......

  <xsl:template match=??$XPathTest$$??> How can the param be used?
     <!--code goes here-->
  </xsl:template>
.........
.......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Instead of using XML DOM and reading Value by using XPath directly in
>   C#, Is it possible to pass string as a param to XSLT and in XSLT use
>   it as XPath?

**Not in XSLT 1.0 or in XSLT 2.0.**

In XSLT 3.0 (still a working draft) one may use the **[`xsl:evaluate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-evaluate)** instruction.

It may be interesting to you to see how the **[XPath Visualizer](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html)** does this: the XPath expression is used to dynamically modify the value of a specific `xsl:variable` -- even before the transformation is invoked.

Disclaimer:

The XPath Visualizer is not for sale and/or profit -- I created it 12 years ago for fun and solely with educational purposes.

Comment: oh! then I will have to wait for that .. probably few months or years .. :) thank you very much for the valuable answer and the add-on, I will try using it for XPath evaluation, I use Notepad++ currently with XML set of Plug-in..

Answer (score 1):

It will work if your XSLT processor implements an xx:evaluate() extension to evaluate an XPath expression supplied as a string. This is quite a common extension, but it's not standard in either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: My I know .. which version of saxon processor supports it?

Comment: All releases 9.1 and earlier had a saxon:evaluate() function. This has been replaced in recent releases by the XSLT 3.0 xsl:evaluate instruction, which is implemented only in Saxon-PE and Saxon-EE.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET transformation engine supports extensions - you can do this by:

- creating an `XsltArgumentList` and calling `AddExtensionObject` with a namespace string and an instance of a class;
- referencing the same namespace string in the stylesheet using `xmlns:prefix=`
- call methods on the extension by simply stating their (qualified) name in the stylesheet i.e. `value-of select='prefix:MyMethod'`

Comment: Thanks for answering. You are mentioning about calling methods in C# Class inside XSLT, using Namespace. I am aware of it. What I need here is using variable as XPath (Value of Select or match attribute) which indeed is not supported in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 (but in 3.0 which is still under development) as mentioned by Mr. Dimitre, and Mr. Michael